# Migrate command create all tables on second DB - Django

Tags: django, django-migrations, django-postgresql

I have an app (`ali`) on my project (`website`) and I wanted it to have its own database. The problem is, when I run `python manage.py migrate --database=ali`, the command recreates all tables within my `ali` database; whereas the expected result would be to have only the `ali_search` database.

P.S.: *the application seems to be running as expected* after I ran some tests. In other words, models from my `ali` app are being saved on the `ali` DB. Still, having all these empty tables inside my `ali` DB is not the correct way to go.

Settings:

```
# website.settings

...

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'base.apps.BaseConfig',
    'ali.apps.AliConfig',
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.sites',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'django.contrib.sitemaps',
    'django_comments',
    'mptt',
    'tagging',
    'zinnia',
]

....

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2',
        'NAME': 'website',
        'USER': 'website',
        'PASSWORD': 'website',
        'HOST': 'localhost',
        'PORT': '5432',
    },
    'ali': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2',
        'NAME': 'ali',
        'USER': 'ali',
        'PASSWORD': 'ali',
        'HOST': 'localhost',
        'PORT': '5432',
    }
}

DATABASE_ROUTERS = [
    'ali.routers.AliRouter',
]

....
```

Router:

```
# ali.routers

class AliRouter:
    def db_for_read(self, model, **hints):
        if model._meta.app_label == 'ali':
            return 'ali'
        return None

    def db_for_write(self, model, **hints):
        if model._meta.app_label == 'ali':
            return 'ali'
        return None

    def allow_relation(self, obj1, obj2, **hints):
        if obj1._meta.app_label == 'ali' or \
           obj2._meta.app_label == 'ali':
           return True
        return None

    def allow_migrate(self, db, app_label, model_name=None, **hints):
        if app_label == 'ali':
            return db == 'ali'
        return None
```

Model:

```
# ali.models

from django.db import models

class Search(models.Model):

    results = models.IntegerField()
```

This is what I get by querying my ali DB with `\dt`:

```
ali=# \dt
                  List of relations
 Schema |            Name            | Type  | Owner 
--------+----------------------------+-------+-------
 public | ali_search                 | table | ali
 public | auth_group                 | table | ali
 public | auth_group_permissions     | table | ali
 public | auth_permission            | table | ali
 public | auth_user                  | table | ali
 public | auth_user_groups           | table | ali
 public | auth_user_user_permissions | table | ali
 public | django_admin_log           | table | ali
 public | django_comment_flags       | table | ali
 public | django_comments            | table | ali
 public | django_content_type        | table | ali
 public | django_migrations          | table | ali
 public | django_session             | table | ali
 public | django_site                | table | ali
 public | tagging_tag                | table | ali
 public | tagging_taggeditem         | table | ali
 public | zinnia_category            | table | ali
 public | zinnia_entry               | table | ali
 public | zinnia_entry_authors       | table | ali
 public | zinnia_entry_categories    | table | ali
 public | zinnia_entry_related       | table | ali
 public | zinnia_entry_sites         | table | ali
(22 rows)
```

But what I would really expect is:

```
ali=# \dt
                  List of relations
 Schema |            Name            | Type  | Owner 
--------+----------------------------+-------+-------
 public | ali_search                 | table | ali
(1 row)
```

Could it be a problem the fact that the app has the same name as the database (in this case, **ali**)?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Returning `None` from `allow_migrate()` means that the router has no opinion on the current operation. If none of the configured routers has an opinion, the default is to allow that operation. Your current router returns `None` for apps other than `ali`, so those operations are allowed on both databases.

To disallow the migrations of other apps on the `ali` database, you have to explicitly return `False` in those cases, for example:

```
def allow_migrate(self, db, app_label, model_name=None, **hints):
    if app_label == 'ali':
        return db == 'ali'
    return db == 'default'
```

Now you can just run `migrate` for each database, without having to specify which apps to migrate:

```
$ python manage.py migrate --database=default
$ python manage.py migrate --database=ali
```

Comment: My bad, forgot to review what I was returning from allow_migrate(). Thank you for the answer, that works perfectly!

Answer (score 0):

For me, the `migrate` command should take a look at the routes in order to create tables. But it seems this is not the case. Therefore, it seems that the easy fix is to call `migrate` with the `[app_label]` argument. Like this:

`python manage.py migrate ali --database=ali`